# How to use the Leibniz Integral Rule for finding the density function of X + Y

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

I'm having a hard time following the derivation of the density function of Z = X + Y. Here is what I have so far:

$\mathbb{P}(Z \leq z) = \mathbb{P}(X+Y \leq z) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x, Y \leq z-x)$.

By definition,

$\mathbb{P}(X \leq x, Y \leq z-x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x}f(x,y)dydx, \hspace{5 mm}$ where f(x,y) is the joint density function of $X,Y$.

Thus,

$\frac{d}{dz}\mathbb{P}(Z \leq z) = f_{Z}(z) = f_{X+Y}(z) = \frac{d}{dz}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x}f(x,y)dydx$.

This is where I have a hard time proceeding.

$\frac{d}{dz}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x}f(x,y)dydx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dz}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x}f(x,y)dydx$.

When reading similar posts, I see it's at this point that we should use Leibniz's integral rule to simplify $\frac{d}{dz}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dy$ to $f(x,z-x)$, but I am uncertain of how this result emerges or how to apply Leibniz's integral rule to this integral in its current form. A detailed derivation using Leibniz's integral rule would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the distribution for the random variables $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Who is the person who downvotes anonymously a well written question like this one ?

Comment: @user1027216 As said in the text, $f$ is the joint pdf. Variables $X$ and $Y$ aren't independent.

Answer (score 1):

RHS of last statement looks wrong.  Should be $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d}{dz}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f(x,y)dydx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,z-x)dx$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out!